# giraph building error at "Apache Giraph Parent"

Tags: maven, hadoop, giraph

Hi i'm trying to build giraph at virtualbox ubuntu.

I followed under two link

http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html

https://lab.hypotheses.org/1207

hadoop worked well but giraph was not installed both of cases...

```
mvn package -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core
[INFO] Apache Giraph Blocks Framework
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples
[INFO] Apache Giraph Accumulo I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph HBase I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph HCatalog I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph Gora I/O
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Giraph Parent 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/1.4/maven-remote-resources-plugin-1.4.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent ............................... FAILURE [  1.126 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Blocks Framework ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Accumulo I/O ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph HBase I/O ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph HCatalog I/O ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Gora I/O ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.995 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-23T23:53:13+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:pom:1.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

are there any information for solving this problem, say to me. i gonna reply as fast as i can.

Comment: in question, please add maven, java version.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_95"          

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)          

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: ko_KR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-45-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: As per this [docs](https://giraph.apache.org/build.html) giraph requires java 1.8 to compile. Install java 1.8 and try.

Comment: Thank you so much!
For other person, after git clone giraph, you should change pop.xml at ./giraph.
<repository> <id><url>http://~~~~  ==>  <repository> <id><url>https://~~~~